# how to Change Date format in android with Proper Month?

Tags: android, date

I want to Change of date format. I am able to change the my date Format 2014-12-09 to MMM dd,yyyy(Dec 09,2014 Like this.) But It Display Jan 09,2014 instead of Dec 09,2014. How to display Dec 09,2014? Why not display proper month? Please Guide me. What is the problem in my code. please Suggest me.

**My Code**

```
        SimpleDateFormat readFormat = null, writeFormat = null;
        Date startDate = null, endDate = null;
        String strStartDate = "2014-12-09";

        readFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
        writeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy");

        try {
            startDate = readFormat.parse(strStartDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        viewHolder.txtStartDate
                .setText(writeFormat.format(startDate));
```

Please Guide me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to understand what is your problem?

Comment: @MD My date is 2014-12-09 but It Display Jan 09,2014 instead of Dec 09,2014. What is the problem in my code?

Comment: just change date of ur phone

Comment: @Milad but its display in every device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try this:

```
readFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");  //notice the capital M's
```

Comment: Thank you, Got the Solution through yyyy-MM-dd